# MongoEngine python empty EmbeddedDocumentList

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am usisng mongo engine and python to store some documents in a mongo DB with an script.

I am using subdocuments Embedded List in the parent document. The main problem is that I needed that in the DDBB is this field is not filled, it wont be event set.
To explain myself better.

[image]

This is the field of my doc. In this case I am not setting it. When I print the document that will be stored is the following

[image]

I am also doing things like that

[image]

And when I see the stored document

[image]

How can I avoid that this field will be stored if its empty?

Answer (score 0):

It was easy
voltageLevel = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentListField(CatalogVoltageLevelsMongo,default=None)

You have to add the default value as None